# Monitoring internet connectivity in many fragments in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using BroadcastReceiver to monitor a possible change in the internet connectivity:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Now, I need to make a check in each fragment in my ViewPager separately. Because if the user becomes connected then that will be reflected on the UI of each fragment separately.

If I assumed that the maximim number of created fragment at a time is three, then my question is:

is it dangerous to define a NetworkChangeReceiver instance for each fragment to work separately, or I should define only one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply apply `Observer Pattern` structure to your problem.

First of all you need to define a inner class that has to be observable by Fragments.

I will paste some code snippets to illustrate how to be applied.

Here is the `NetworkChangeReceiver` and `NetworkObservable` class.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d("NetworkChangeReceiver","Connection status changed");
        getObservable().connectionChanged();
    }

    public static class NetworkObservable extends Observable{
        private static NetworkObservable instance = null;

        private NetworkObservable() {
            // Exist to defeat instantiation.
        }

        public void connectionChanged(){
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }

        public static NetworkObservable getInstance(){
             if(instance == null){
                 instance = new NetworkObservable();
             }
             return instance;
        }
    }

    public static NetworkObservable getObservable() {
        return NetworkObservable.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Moreover, you need to setup your manifest for broadcast receiver. Here is how you can do it:

```
<receiver android:name="com.your.package.name.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Whenever your connection changes `onReceive` method implicitly called. Therefore, you need to call a method that notifies all the observers.

For your situation, observers will be `Fragment` classes.

I'll paste another code block to show a sample observer class.

```
/*
* If you have memory concerns,
* you need to add your observer while application is resuming
* you need to remove that observer object while application is pausing...
* 
*/
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements Observer{        
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      NetworkChangeReceiver.getObservable().deleteObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      NetworkChangeReceiver.getObservable().addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        // Whenever connection changes, this method will be called so edit your text here
    }
}
```

You can also pass the network status by adding any parameter to `notiftyObservers()` method.

Hope this may help.

Comment: now let me ask you, is it ok NOT to delete myself from the observer in onDestry() method? the fragment that was added as observer was supposed to be destroyed and internet connection state also changed without giving me any error. I just want to make sure.

Comment: Nope that's a memory leak bro, you have to handle this issue as well because your application will throw an exception while it's in the background. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks gokhanakkurt for your answer, but I don't know why 'update' function has not been invoked until I made 'observable' object a singleton!

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static NetworkObservable observable;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        getObservable().connectionChanged();
    }

    public static class NetworkObservable extends Observable
    {
        public void connectionChanged()
        {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();          
        }
    }

    public static NetworkObservable getObservable()
    {
        if(observable == null)
        {
            observable = new NetworkObservable();
        }

        return observable;
    }
}
```

and in my fragment:

```
NetworkStateReceiver.getObservable().addObserver(this);
```

Hope you check and modify your answer if I'm correct or clarify if you're correct. Anyway, your answer is still accepted.

Comment: Your code is not the same as mine. If you return a new object in each call getObservable() that will not work. Because each instance will have different observers. Therefore, update will not be called. In your case you have to have one observable object(not more than one) which must be either singleton or static object that notifies registered observers. I'll edit your code block.

Comment: but it's a singleton in my case and its working. do you mean you want to edit your code block?

Comment: I mean i have seen some leaks on your code. Actually you can still create NetworkObservable object by default. You have to prevent your code from this action. But other is fine. That's all correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this as following and this is working fine

---

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
    TextView noInternetView;

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String status = getConnectivityStatusString(context);

            if(status.equals("No")) {
                noInternetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                noInternetView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    };

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = null;
        if (conn == TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = "Wifi";//"Wifi enabled";
        } else if (conn == TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = "Mobile";//"Mobile data enabled";
        } else if (conn == TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = "No";//"Not connected to Internet";
        }
        return status;
    }

    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

        noInternetView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nointernet);
        .......
        .......

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();
      getActivity().getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
}
```

**first_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#DFE6F5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nointernet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"         
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:text="No internet connection!"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a `static boolean` variable set in `onReceive` (`true` when connection is on, and `false` otherwise) and retrieve the value in `onCreateView`  or `onResume` of your different fragments.